# Archiving the contents of a directory where files are older than X days old

Tags: powershell, filtering, archiving

I have been trying to put together a simple script to archive the contents of a directory that are older than 7 days old, eventually I want to have the script remove the old text file, but so far I haven't been able to get the script to archive only files older than my specified range.

What I have so far is this:

```
## Alias for 7zip
$sz = "C:\scripts\7z\7za.exe"

## Directory location
$path = "(Directory to archive)"

## Get current date and adjust it by 7 days
$limit = (get-date).AddDays(-7)

## create an array of files based on filetype, adjusted to the previously specified adjusted date 
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -force -include *.txt -Exclude *.zip | ? { !$_.CreationTime -lt $limit }

foreach ($file in $files){
& $sz a -tzip ($file.Name+".zip") $file.Name}
```

I thank you in advance for any advice you can provide me.

Comment: This would be much better to implement with Robocopy. Use Robocopy to move your files that need to be archived to a new directory (it can search a path, recursively, based on age), then zip up everything in that directory. It'll be much faster than a pure PowerShell solution.

Comment: The files are essentially a repository of dump data for a client, it does not need to be transported anywhere, I simply need to archive files older than 7 days old, leaving a uncompressed copy for only a weeks duration.

Comment: That's fine. But Robocopy will do this much cleaner & faster. `robocopy.exe SOURCEDIR DESTDIR /MINAGE:7 /MOV` will move all files older than 7 days to `DESTDIR` And it **will** be faster than `Get-ChildItem` plus filtering. Then `foreach` over the files in `DESTDIR` and zip them.

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting concept, I will see if I can mock this up and see how that method would work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
## Alias for 7zip
$sz = "C:\scripts\7z\7za.exe"

## Directory location
$path = "(Directory to archive)"

## Get current date and adjust it by 7 days
$limit = (get-date).AddDays(-7)

## create an array of files based on filetype, adjusted to the previously specified adjusted date 
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -force -filter *.txt | ? { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }

foreach ($file in $files){
& $sz a -tzip ($file.Name+".zip") $file.Name
```

simplified get-childitem, corrected where-object-script

Comment: With those changes, it now only creates one single zip file instead of the desired individual files.

Comment: are the zipped files the files you wanted?

Comment: The files originate as text files, the process I want to end up with will be to archive files that are older than 7 days, in to their own individual zip, and then delete the original text file leaving only the zip file.

The deletion part will come later, but for the time being, getting the zip process to adhere to the 7 day range is what I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked through it and found the answer.

```
## Files Zipper v1.0

## Author: Xander J
## Creation date: 03/06/2016

## Description: Archives text files in the "directory location" older than 7 days

## alias for 7zip
    $sz = "C:\scripts\exe\7za.exe"
    Set-Alias sz $sz

## directory location
    $path = "(Location on files to be archived)"

## create an array of files based on filetype, adjusted to the previously specified adjusted date 
    $files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -force -include *.txt -Exclude *.zip | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt "01-01-1900" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7) }

## perform 7zip operation on all files that meed date criteria
foreach ($file in $files){
    sz a -tzip ($file.Name+".zip") $file.Name
    remove-item $file.Name
}
```

I tried working with Robocopy, but I found it to be problematic at best, and I really wanted to use as few external exe's as possible.

I'm posting this here in hopes that it helps someone else in the future, thank you for the feedback guys, I appreciate your time.